# Get class type from static method (on base class)

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to get the derived class type from a static method defined in the base class.
The structure looks like:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public static Type GetType()
    {
        return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetType();
    }
}

class Foo : BaseClass
{
}
```

I need the code `Foo.GetType()` to return **Foo** but it returns **BaseClass** :(
I have to get type without using generics or initializing an instance.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`typeof(Foo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  Without more context on what you're doing, it looks like that should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Foo` doesn't redeclare `GetType`, `Foo.GetType()` is effectively the same method as `BaseClass.GetType()`. So when you write `Foo.GetType()`, the compiler emits a call to `BaseClass.GetType()`, since `BaseClass` is the type that actually implements the method.

Anyway, what you're doing doesn't make sense ; if you write `Foo.GetType()`, you already know that you want it to return `Foo`, so you can just use `typeof(Foo)`.